# Is it possible to send 'left arrow' to the OMXPlayer console?

Tags: python, keyboard, omxplayer

I'm building a MP3 player with physical buttons using a Raspberry Pi and Python. I'm using the `subprocess` library to allow simultaneous actions without blocking user input.

I'm sending commands to the OMXPlayer terminal with commands like these:

```
    # opening the audio file, playing
    player = subprocess.Popen(["omxplayer",newsItems[index]],stdin=subprocess.PIPE) #,stdout=subprocess.PIPE,stderr=subprocess.PIPE

    # pause/resume items
    player.stdin.write("p")

    # quit playing
    player.stdin.write("q")
```

I would like to use `player.stdin.write("left arrow")` to make the audio playback go back 30 seconds, but I can't get it to work.

Comment: think about what `player.stdin.write("left arrow")` actually does .... it sends 10 keypresses to the player

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution. For others with a similar problem, here is how you should fix it:

Instead of using

```
  player.stdin.write("left arrow")
```

You should use

```
  player.stdin.write("^[[D")
```

Here are the keycodes to all arrow keys:

```
arrow-up:      ^[[A
arrow-down:    ^[[B
arrow-right:   ^[[C
arrow-left:    ^[[D
```